Зависла загрузка плагина в VS Code
загружала плагин algoritmika в уже установленный vs code на макбуке; модуль похоже не установился и теперь идет вечное обновление и vs code просто вылетает каждые секунд 5.
я полностью удаляла vs code с макбук и устанавливала заново с официального сайта, но это никак не помогло

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
